# Жесты box2d

Tags: box2d, ios, iphone, cocos2d

Можем ли мы отследить жесты "смахивания", или слайдинга.
Иначе говоря делаем жест влево на боксовском объекте, объект смещается на 10 пикселей влево. Также с жестом вверх, назад, вправо.
Идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы не попробовали воспользоваться ссылкой из верхнего комментария??? 
Возможно мой ответ далек от совершенства но я думаю попробовать стоит, суть его в том что, для того что бы переместить тело из точки А в точку Б нам необходимо приложить некое "усилие" к телу то есть другими словами придать телу некий импульс и вектор движения(физики, простите меня, если я неправельно выразился). Так, то есть имеем тело создалось в точке А - это будет скажем так отправной точкой тела и имеем точку Б, точка Б - это точка куда должно прибыть тело, дальше дело техники:

```
(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0,0));

   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

   location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

   b2Vec2 pos = ballBody->GetPosition();

   b2Vec2 impulse = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO - pos.x, location.y/PTM_RATIO - pos.y);

   ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulse, pos);

   return YES;}
```

В этом случае тело будет двигаться из точки А в точку Б ... НО есть одно после достижения точки Б тело может продолжить свое движение дальше...

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно так сделать, почему нет, но нужно учесть, что что в box2d тела двигаются под действием силы которую к ним прикладывают. Есть несколько вариантов того,что вы хотите сделать. К примеру первый вариант это использование Joint'ов хотя он тут не совсем уместен, лучше я думаю использовать методы типа Touch. [думаю стоит прочитать](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7219)

Comment: Ну Joint не подходит.Тут при таче планируется статическое смещение на N пикселов.

Comment: Давайте с начала условимся, двигать тело будем с анимацией, то есть провели пальцем по дисплею поймали евент типа TouchMoved и тело по этой траектории двигается или ткнули пальцем и тело туда перенеслось, как вы хотите сделать?

З.Ы. думаю стоит ознакомится http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922953/box2dmove-body-with-animation

Comment: Да, допусти сделали жест пальцем влево, тело с анимацией двинулось на 20 пикселей. Сделали жест пальцем вверх, тело с анимацией двинулось на 20 пикселей вверх.